# Scanf_s is empty in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scanf

I can't use this code because I can't write any text. 
How can i solve this problem with reading?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "string.h"




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char str[1024];

    printf("Input text: ");
    scanf_s("%c", str);

    _asm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    {
    //some assembly code
    }


    printf("\n\nResult = %s", str);

    printf("\n\n[Press any key]");
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

result is

```
Input text: sdf

Result =

[Press any key]
```

any ideas? I use Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: what happens in `//some assembly code`?

Comment: If you're using C++ (as per the question's tag), why not use C++ I/O (e.g. `std::string str; std::cin >> str;`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't know the function `scanf_s`, so I looked up the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w40768et%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It notes, that in constrast to `scanf` for `scanf_s` buffer sizes need to be specified for format specifiers `c`, `C`, `s` and `S` as a second parameter following the usual one. An example:

```
char str[1024];

printf("Input text: ");
scanf_s("%s", str, 1024);
```

The documentation also states that in case of potential buffer overflow nothing is written to the buffer.

Comment: So basically it means, that without buffer size specified it will crash?

Answer (score 2):

The `%c` format specifier in

```
scanf_s("%c", str);
```

requests that a single `char` is read.

```
printf("\n\nResult = %s", str);
```

later requests that the contents of `str` until the first `char` with value `'\0'` are printed.  This results in undefined behaviour since you only initialised the first element of `str`.  You may sometimes manage to print a range of stack memory; other times your program will crash.

Assuming you want to read a nul-terminated array of chars, you need to use the `%s` format specifier when reading user input instead:

```
scanf_s("%s", str);
```

Comment: It works for me after making this change.  I'd guess there are bugs in the "some assembly code" you haven't shown.  This might also explain why you get no output rather than junk from the stack.

Comment: @user2121707 See my answer below. simonc You tried with string with whitespaces?

Comment: @Digital_Reality I know that the code will only read a single word. Its possible this isn't what the OP expects but I don't see anything in the question suggesting that.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below..

```
scanf("%[0-9a-zA-Z ]s", str);
```

%c will only read one char from input value.

%s will read one word (till whitespaces)

[scanf %s](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

```
Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found. A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I gathered several answers and I got the user to write his name with spaces and numbers, Thanks!

```
"#include "stdafx.h"

"#include < iostream >"

"#include < stdio.h >"

"#include < locale.h >"

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    char a [100];

    printf_s("\n Programa para la práctica de scanf_s ");
    printf_s("\n Introduzca su nombre completo: ");
    scanf_s("%[0-9a-zA-Z        ]s", &a, 100);
    printf_s("\n ¡Bienvenido! Sr. %s", a);

    cout << " \n This is a white space\n "<<a;
    system("PAUSE()");
    return 0;
}
```